# ServiceStack serializing a JsonObject with JsonSerializer produces an invalid json Date

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I am using service ServiceStack JsonObject.Parse to deserialize unknown types.

After that I use ServiceStack JsonSerializer.SerializeToString to reserialize back to json.

The object has a DateTime property on it, and when it is re-serialized, the json is incorrect for a Date

here is the example code

```
void Main()
{
    var p = new Person { Name = "full name", Age = new DateTime(2000,1,1) };
    var json = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(p);
    Console.WriteLine(json);

    var jo = ServiceStack.Text.JsonObject.Parse(json);
    var json2 = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(jo);
    Console.WriteLine(json2);
}

class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime Age {get;set;}
}
```

and the results (notice the extra slashes around the date)

```
{"Name":"full name","Age":"\/Date(946713600000-0000)\/"}
{"Name":"full name","Age":"\\/Date(946713600000-0000)\\/"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to `JsonObject` just being a wrapper around `Dictionary<string,string>`, i.e:

```
public class JsonObject : Dictionary<string, string> { ... }
```

So when the `JsonObject` is serialized the Date Value is instead serialized as a `string` value where the `\` get appropriately escaped.

Unfortunately WCF's JSON format chose to use the `\/Date(..)\/` format since it's unlikely to ever be produced naturally as forward slashes (i.e. `/`) aren't needed to be or are normally escaped.

One solution is to just change the JSON Date format used, i.e:

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601
```

Comment: Unfortunately the original json messages are serialized with WCF as you pointed out. Additionally later in the chain these messages are deserialized by processes that are bound to using XmlObjectSerializer derivatives such as DataContractJsonSerializer